# How to add absolute positioned elements dynamically to a DOM container without the elements colliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation, jsplumb

I have a div#container to which I am dynamically adding rectangles and circles of various sizes. These rectangles and circles are manually positioned, with position : absolute .  Now how I do determine where to position these dynamically added elements. I dont want to place an element on top of the other.

As of now Whenever I add a new element to the container, I position in 10px below and 10px to the right of the previous element. This is not a optimal way. I might over run the container quickly.

After I have run out of space on the container , I want to introduce scrollbars

[image]

Comment: Far too open a question when there is no expected results indicated or what these elements are. Where's your code and layout?

Comment: @charlietfl Whenever I add a new element to the container, I position in 10px below and 10px to the right of the previous element. This is not a optimal way. I might over run the container quickly.  I have added a pic to describe. Let me know if its okay now

Comment: Should update question with that comment along with your current code and what should happen at perimter of container

Comment: @charlietfl I have done the same. I guess it looks good now. Thank you very much

Comment: @codeAnand see my updated answer's demo that will give you idea of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @A.B Your solution works. But lets say, I delete an element in the middle. I want to add the new node to that deleted place

Comment: you can notes its offsetLeft before deleting and add there. i can edit the answer if you want